# Google analytics for android working but... Where can i check which sections/events of my app have been opened?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I can see that GoogleAnalytics web tell me that one guy has done 11 visits to my Android App

Its working but.... i dont know where i can check which sections/events of my app have been opened, and i have `tracker.trackPageView("/section");` and `tracker.trackEvent("licks", "Button", "clicked", 77);`in each section/action

where i can see it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to google analytics and it is here --> Standard Reporting / Content / Events / Overview, you can find there those events :-)